# Change volume % that changes every time I decrease it from keyboard

Tags: linux, fedora, alsa, volume

So basically from what I found out from amixer, every time I press fn and the arrows of the keyboard to change the volume, the % of volume changing is 6%. I would like to make that 1%. How can this be done?

Comment: the function keys are very likely interpreted by your window manager - which one are you using and which distribution ?